# Basic GdkWindow hello world Example?

Tags: c++, c, linux, gtk, gdk

I'm new to Gtk/Gdk.

I've done some work with GtkWindows, but now I need to work with lower level Gdk Windows. 
I understand GdkWindows are used to implement GtkWindows and GtkWidgets in general. It is the drawing area.

I'm kind of not sure where to start. How do I make a shell, with a GdkWindow inside it with something like a label inside that saying hello world?

I've looked around for tutorials, but haven't been able to find anything.

**Edit - background for this**
I can't get away with just knowing Gtk. The reason I need to work on Gdk.

- I'm an SWT/Gtk developer.
- SWT is build on top of Gtk/Gdk.
- For gtk3, it has a [custom container](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/plain/bundles/org.eclipse.swt/Eclipse%20SWT%20PI/gtk/library/os_custom.c), to allow things like overlapping IDE elements.
- The custom container uses low-level Gdk calls, (e.g for realization).
- It's [buggy](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=457476). I need to fix it. Thus need to learn Gdk.

Comment: Under what requirements would you be able to use Gdk and not Gtk?  Are you sure you want that?   You're in for a world of pain...  think "pixel by pixel rendering of UI elements"

Comment: Yah, Gdk is meh to learn. But I kinda have to. I edited question to reflect reasoning.

Comment: Ugh, sounds hateful.   I doubt you'll find a tutorial, but maybe the gtk source implementation of DnD will be helpful?   You'll have to get into DnD protocols and such:  https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-Drag-and-Drop.html#gdk-window-get-drag-protocol

Comment: Good luck.   Maybe ask for some sample code on the gtk dev list?  What you're doing is really, really specialized...